# document.activeElement in iframe shows unspecified error in IE standards mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
console.log(document.activeElement);
```

This code is in an iframe, when opening a page which contains this iframe shows "SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error" in IE 8/9 standards mode. No problem when opening in quirks mode. I'm clueless about this, I have searched whether IE supports document.activeElement, its specified as >IE4 is supported.

Comment: check this link if it helps you.. http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/window-radopen-gives-document-activeelement-unspecified-error.aspx

Comment: When are you calling this code? Before or after the iframe document has loaded?

Comment: @ABCD Thanks for the link. As specified in the link, using document.documentElement.focus() before using document.activeElement resolves the issue.

Comment: @TimDown In $(document).ready

Comment: @BalajiSivanath:Can you mark my comment as useful? :)

Comment: @ABCD How to mark it? I am not having any option, may be due to low reputation

Comment: i am editing my comment as answer..plz accept it if u can ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check the below given link if it helps you.. 
`Link`

Comment: Came here off a google search, the given link is long dead.

This is why you transcribe the relevant information from a link into the post itself.

Answer (score 6):

If you have jquery, try the following workaround:

```
<script>
         jQuery(function () { document.documentElement.focus(); });
    </script>
```

Comment: This did not exactly work for me when it was inside a function.
only added this `<script>document.documentElement.focus();</script>` then it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try add header

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

work for me whitout change my javascript code.